# How do I delete a partiton and allocate the space to my main Ubuntu partition?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have a partition table that looks like this in gparted:

[image: gparted partition table]

I want to delete the /dev/sda6 partition and allocate the space to my main sda1 partition, and also allocate the unallocated space to it as well.  How do I do this, please?  Warning: I am a noob with linux!

Answer (score 2):

Right click on /dev/sda6, and select delete. Then right click on sda1 and select resize/move. increase the storage until there is no free space following it. click resize/move and then click on the tick in the top of gparted.

Comment: Please note in the image, that /sda6 is *inside* /sda2.  At the very least /sda2 will need to be shrunk, and probably moved to make the empty space contiguous with /sda1

Comment: I am unable to resize sda1, and don't know how to merge sda2 and sda1, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Boot with live USB/DVD in gparted.

1. Since  except the swap on 'sda5' no space is being used as 'sda6' is to be deleted. I would suggest that `swapoff -a` and delete 'sda2'.
2. resize 'sda1'.
3. Create new swap partition.

Then mount the Ubuntu partition.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

Find the UUID of Ubuntu and swap partitions.

```
sudo blkid -o full -s UUID
```

Edit /etc/fstab file

```
sudo gedit /mnt/etc/fstab
```

Change the UUID entries of "/" (Ubuntu) and swap partitionsin /etc/fstab

Save and close.

Reboot